# URL RewriteRule in .htaccess for index.php query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Example URL's:-

- www.domain.com/index.php?bob
- www.domain.com/index.php?jane
- www.domain.com/index.php?fred

Need rewriting like:-

- www.domain.com/bob
- www.domain.com/jane
- www.domain.com/fred

Have tried with many variations now but the closest I can get to is:-

- www.domain.com/?bob
- www.domain.com/?jane
- www.domain.com/?fred

The below in .htaccess achieves this...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Please could someone point out what I need to modify to bin the ? (question mark) in the URL?

### Edit

Just noticed that since applying the answer given by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) below that robots.txt for example doesn't resolve to the .txt file but just displays the homepage.

.htaccess below:-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#pos1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA] <--

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

#pos2
```

If I add the <-- line in pos1, the robots.txt URL returns a 404 page not found error.

If I add the <-- line in pos2, the robots.txt URL just displays the homepage.

### Edit2

In the meantime, I have excluded `robots.txt` from rewrites by adding the following under `Rewrite Base /`:-

```
RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! (Will accept answer as soon as SO allows me to).

Comment: I noticed an issue actually with URL's not resolving to the correct locations since applying your answer. I edited my question to include an example - I think it is due to the incorrect order in `.htaccess`? Thanks.

Comment: Checked our code. Don't you have conflicting rules 1: `index.php?_route_=$1` and 2: `index.php?$1` only one of these rewrites will work. Yes `RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]` will sure work.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for confirming - yeah the other one is a default OpenCart rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```