# Redirect from querystring url to preety url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is on a free webhosting company www.000webhost.com , Htaccess in enabled on that host. My question is : can I redirect a long url to short one?

forexample :

if I enter

www.example.com/u/map.php?q=foo

it will redirect to

www.example.com/map/foo

and if I enter

www.example.com/map/foo

Please help!

Comment: Yes, it's possible , but you're question is not clear specially the last part!

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL RewriteRule in .htaccess for index.php query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854952/url-rewriterule-in-htaccess-for-index-php-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect www.example.com/u/map.php?q=foo to www.example.com/map/foo and www.example.com/map/foo (internally) to www.example.com/u/map.php?q=foo , then

Try this in Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /u/map\.php\?q=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /map/%1? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^map/([^/]+)/?$ /u/map.php?q=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```