# Why PHP router gives me error 301 moved permanently?

Tags: php, routes

I'm making **RestAPI** in **PHP** with a route controller written by me, anything works with my code and my current .htaccess settings:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]
```

**http://restapi/user/134723339?&authkey=XXXX** returns user datas correctly.

Now, with **http://restapi/user?&authkey=XXXX** i would like to get **ALL** user datas but it keeps give me the **301 Moved Permanently** status and no output.

Is it an **.htaccess** problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a suggestion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854952/url-rewriterule-in-htaccess-for-index-php-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, URL would remain the same. so htaccess is working

for case 1 (**http://restapi/user/134723339?&authkey=XXXX**)

**http://restapi.com/index.php?&authkey=XXXX**

for case 2 (**http://restapi/user?&authkey=XXXX** )
**http://restapi.com/index.php?&authkey=XXXX**

Comment: But the 2nd case is the only one gives me this error. Maybe is a router class problem?

Comment: Printing the uri in the 1st case returns this: /user/134723339?&authkey=XXXX while printing the uri in the 2nd case returns this: /index.php?&authkey=XXXX

Comment: if that would be the case then seems the htaccess is not working. You are getting what is passed in the URL no rewriting is happening.

Comment: Yes, i think so. But i really don't know how to properly write the redirect rule.